# What means a combined All with Any LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq

I have a line of code:

```
bool true/false = array1.All(a => array2.Any(t => t.field == a.field));
```

I do not understand this combination of all + any.

Does it mean 'No field of array1 equals any field of array2' then return true ?

Would this not be the same as `array1.Except(array2).Any();` ?

**UPDATE**

Accidently I put a "!" before the .Any() !!!

Comment: No, they're completely different. For one thing, you're not even checking the field in your alternative.

Comment: That means that value is true if no member of array1 is in array2.

Comment: That is why negative operator `!` is a bad for readability

Comment: `array1.Select(t => t.field).Except(array2.Select(a => a.field)).Any();`

Comment: More readable would be `array1.All(a1 => array2.All(a2  => a1.field != a2.field))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think they are really different, it also depends on how you `array` is structured. If it has only `field` property or it has other properties as well.

---

### Code inspection

```
array1.All(a => array2.Any(t => t.field == a.field));
```

> Return true if For each element in array1 there's **at least one** element in array2 that has the
>   same value for the `field` property

---

```
array1.Except(array2).Any();
```

> Return True if there's at least one element of `array1` not present in
>   `array2`

---

Now given your context, if `field` is the only property of your structure it produces the same result, but it does not if there's other things going on.

For example

```
struct Test
{
  public string int { get; set; }
  public string int { get; set; }
}

//...

var array1 = new Test[] 
{
  new Test { Field = 0, OtherField = 1 },
  new Test { Field = 1, OtherField = 2 }
}

var array2 = new Test[] 
{
  new Test { Field = 0, OtherField = 1 },
  new Test { Field = 2, OtherField = 2 }
}
```

**First case**: is it true that for each element of `array1` there's at least one element in `array2` with same value in field property? **False**

**Second case**: is it true that at least one element of `array1` is not present in `array2`? **True**

Comment: I have UPDATEd my question, would you please be that kind and modify your answer!?

Comment: Does it not rather mean: all array1 items must be present on array2 ?Would an alternate way to write the query something like then: array1.IntersectAllItemsOf(array2)

Comment: `!array1.Except(array2).Any();` add the `!` operator in front of your statement :)

Answer (score 1):

That means return true if there is no item in array2 which has the same value in field for all of items in array1.

Simpler version:

For all items in array1, there is no item in array2 with same value of field.

UPDATE:

Now the modified version is much simpler since it says return true if for all items in array1 there is an item in array2 with same value for field.

Comment: I have UPDATEd my question, would you please be that kind and modify your answer!?

Answer (score 0):

In summary, your first solution is to check if all the elements in `array1` have the same `field` value in some element in `array2`, which could be also translated to:

```
var areContained =!array1.Select(e=>e.field)).Except(array2.Select(d=>d.field)).Any();
```

Another variant could be using a hash that could help to the efficiency if the superset if too big:

```
HashSet<int> hashSet = new HashSet<int>(array2.Select(d=>d.field));//Superset
bool contained = array1.Select(e=>e.field)).All(i => hashSet.Contains(i));
```

In your alternative you are comparing based on object instances of the arrays by using the default equality comparer, so that can produce a completely different result. Take a look the example in this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336390(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I have UPDATEd my question, would you please be that kind and modify your answer!?